# Syntax error near unexpected token 'else'

Tags: bash

I have looked at this for about 30 minutes now and can't seem to find the error in this. It happens at my if/else block at the end.

```
default()
{
for file in /*
do
        if [ -f $file ]; then
                ((filecount++))
        elif [ -d $file ]; then
                ((dircount++))
        fi
done
echo The number of files is "$filecount"
echo The number of directories is "$dircount"
}
specific()
{
for file in $param
do
        if [ -f $file ]; then
                ((filecount++))
        elif [ -d $file ]; then
                ((dircount++))
        fi
done
echo The number of files is "$filecount"
echo The number of directories is "$dircount"
}
#Variables
declare -a param=$1
declare -i filecount="0"
declare -i dircount="0"
#Action
if [ $param=='-h' ]; then
        echo To use this program, enter a directory path after $0 or leave it blank to use current directory.
elif [ $param=='' ]; then
        default()
else
        specific()
fi
exit 0
```

Here is the error code. Any help is appreciated.

```
./countf.sh: line 44: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./countf.sh: line 44: `else'
```

Comment: You don't call shell functions as `default()` you call them as `default`.

Comment: Thank you this cleared up the problem. Now on to my other issues.

Comment: Proper form here is one issue to a question, and no more code in that question than is necessary for the single issue it covers. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, I'd suggest running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the issues it finds before requesting human review. Reading through http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can't agree more

Comment: You need more space.  `if [ $param=='-h' ]` must have spaces around the `==` and should use `=` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your syntax only and found these errors.

1. function calls. As @Etan Reisner mentioned.
2. You need spaces around the comparison operator. like  `[ $param == '-h' ]`;
3. you need to double quote your variable. use `[ "$param" == '-h' ]` instead of `[ $param == '-h' ]` . Check this for more details. [Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086#double-quote-to-prevent-globbing-and-word-splitting)

I suggest you to test your script here. http://www.shellcheck.net/ I also should do that first instead of manually check your script.

Comment: now i'm getting an error if I run default without parameters `./countf.sh: line 35: [: ==: unary operator expected
` and `./countf.sh: line 37: [: ==: unary operator expected
`

Comment: When I run it, it's totally fine. what's the error?

Comment: sorry new to stack overflow and learning formatting, i edited my comment above

Comment: oh. sorry. I miss the error. you need to double quote your variable. I edited the answer

Comment: Another gotcha not mentioned here -- `==` is a bash extension; POSIX only requires support for `=`, not `==`.